# Subscribe to YouTube channels without account

Tags: web-browser, youtube, plug-in

When you are signed in on YouTube then on your [subscription feed](https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions) youtube show a list sorted by date of the videos the youtube channels you subscribed to have uploaded.

as i am subscribed to a handfull of tech / it youtubers just to stay up to date, this is the only reason I "need" a account for youtube.

So, I was interested if there was a way to accomplish this task trough other means, anything from a browser plugin "simulating" the subscription feed, to a bash script which just outputs a list of the title and the link to the video

Comment: create fake account just for youtube? what is your concern with having an account?

Comment: @depperm: There are valid reasons for not wanting to have an account. When you create an account you have to accept some terms, it is never really fake.

Answer (score 1):

[newpipe](https://newpipe.net/) does not required an account and you can [migrate](https://newpipe.net/FAQ/tutorials/import-export-data/) our subscriptions over from YouTube but is only available on Android

Answer (score 0):

[YouTube Subscription Manager](https://github.com/chibicitiberiu/ytsm) allows you to systematically download your subscriptions but would still require a YouTube account

Comment: This is really 2 answers.  Would you mind breaking it up into 2 separate posts, so the community can vote on each answer individually?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any feed reader (e.g. [Akregator](https://apps.kde.org/akregator/)).

For each channel, add the feed URL `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC...` where `UC...` is the channel ID. If the channel has a regular username, the correct feed URL is `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=NAME`.